# Mysql Why is the count(*) performance very fast after locking a table

Tags: mysql, count

If I don't lock the table, the count(*) performance was bad like this:

```sql
mysql> select count(*) from titles;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   443308 |
+----------+
1 row in set (8.79 sec)

mysql> explain select count(*) from titles;
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | titles | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 209     | NULL | 442843 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

It looks so normal. But when I lock the table, the count(*) performance was so fast.

```sql
mysql> lock tables titles read;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from titles;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   443308 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.13 sec)
```

What happens to the operation of count after locking the table?

update at 2021-5-29:

```sql
mysql> show index from titles;
+--------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| titles |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | emp_no      | A         |      301411 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| titles |          0 | PRIMARY    |            2 | title       | A         |      441772 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| titles |          0 | PRIMARY    |            3 | from_date   | A         |      442843 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| titles |          1 | idx_emp_no |            1 | emp_no      | A         |      300876 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> explain select count(*) from titles;
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | titles | NULL       | index | NULL          | idx_emp_no | 4       | NULL | 442835 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from titles;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   443304 |
+----------+
1 row in set (8.79 sec)
```

I create an smaller index. But it doesn't have any change.

Comment: Could you try this in the reverse order (eg: first query with lock and then without lock) it could be basically product of query cache. Also, which table ENGINE is used could affect the query time (INNODB MYISAM)

Comment: @F.Igor. I tried many times. It makes no difference. It uses InnoDB. Maybe I should check if the cache is normal?

Comment: But I didn't open the query cache. Maybe it will open query cache when I lock the table?

Comment: @F.Igor - If the Query cache were involved, it would not take 130ms, but rather more like 1ms.  Instead it is probably the buffer_pool doing g the caching.

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: @RickJames Mysql 8.0.22. But if it is the result of caching, why does the speed slow down after unlocking?

Comment: Is the table `PARTITIONed`?

Comment: No, it is just an example table from MySQL doc.

Answer (score 0):

Strange.  I get the opposite (6x slower *with*  the LOCK):

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM allcountries;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
| 11082175 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.26 sec)

mysql> LOCK TABLES allcountries READ;
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM allcountries;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
| 11082175 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.59 sec)

mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;

mysql> LOCK TABLES allcountries READ;
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM allcountries;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
| 11082175 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.50 sec)

mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM allcountries;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
| 11082175 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.28 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@version;
+-------------------------+
| @@version               |
+-------------------------+
| 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The table is not `PARTITIONed`.  `innodb_parallel_read_threads` = 4.

**Parallel execution**

8.0 has a few cases where multiple threads are used for queries.  Here are some entries from the Changelogs.  (Still, it does not explain why `LOCK TABLES` is relevant.)

- 8.0.14 Parallel scanning of by PRIMARY KEY (cf innodb_parallel_read_threads) COUNT(*) w/o WHERE
- 8.0.17 Parallel scanning of partitions (cf innodb_parallel_read_threads)
- 8.0.20 Changes to parallel read threads functionality introduced in MySQL 8.0.17 caused a degradation in SELECT COUNT(*) performance. Pages were read from disk unnecessarily. (Bug #30766089)

What was the value of `innodb_parallel_read_threads`?  (`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_parallel_read_threads';`)

Comment: The value is 4.

Answer (score 0):

I've found no relation between table locks and Query time, but looking into the Mysql Manual I've found some clues:

- The COUNT(*) is calculated by scanning the smallest secondary index if any, otherwise it uses the clustered index (primary key or auto-generated)
- Locking the table could lead to an update of all records into the buffer pool, so it does not need to perform additional scans and then returns quicky
- Your primary index key length is 209 which makes the index scan slow, and any SELECT statement could be subject to different optimizations depending on the current table and buffer pool status. (try using a small numeric primary key with unique row id and additional index with all your fields in the current primary key)

In the following link you can find more information

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count

> COUNT(expr) [over_clause]
>
> As of **MySQL 8.0.13**, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name` query performance
> for InnoDB tables is optimized for single-threaded workloads if there
> are no extra clauses such as WHERE or GROUP BY.
>
> InnoDB processes `SELECT COUNT(*)` statements by *traversing the smallest
> available secondary index unless an index or optimizer hint directs
> the optimizer to use a different index*. If a secondary index is not
> present, InnoDB processes SELECT COUNT(*) statements by scanning the
> clustered index.
>
> Processing `SELECT COUNT(*)` statements takes some time if index records
> are not entirely in the buffer pool.
>
> If an approximate row count is sufficient, use `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.
>
> InnoDB handles `SELECT COUNT(*)` and `SELECT COUNT(1)` operations in the
> same way. ***There is no performance difference***.
>
> For MyISAM tables, `COUNT(*)` is optimized to return very quickly if the
> `SELECT` retrieves from one table, no other columns are retrieved, and
> there is no `WHERE` clause.
> This optimization only applies to
> MyISAM tables, because an exact row count is stored for this storage
> engine and can be accessed very quickly. `COUNT(1)` is only subject to
> the same optimization if the first column is defined as NOT NULL.

Comment: Hello, I update my question. I added an index but it still took more than 8 seconds

Comment: Where can I check if it is loaded into the buffer pool?